# C# Regex.Replace with existing word

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to highlight text in a string of text using Regex.Replace which is working, but when I search for the word "problem" I want "problems" to also highlight just not the "s". It highlights right now but replaces "problems" with "problem". How can I know if the current match has an "s" at the end?
This is what I'm using

```
e.Row.Cells[6].Text = Regex.Replace(
    e.Row.Cells[6].Text, 
    "\\b" + Session["filterWord"].ToString() + "[s]{0,1}\\b", 
    "<b><font color=\"red\">" + Session["filterWord"].ToString() + "</font></b>", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following (capture groups):

```
e.Row.Cells[6].Text = Regex.Replace(
    e.Row.Cells[6].Text, 
    "\\b" + Session["filterWord"].ToString() + "([s]?)\\b", 
    "<b><font color=\"red\">" + Session["filterWord"].ToString() + "$1</font></b>", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Changing the search string to capture more, ie to `"\\b(" + Session["filterWord"].ToString() + "[s]?)\\b"` and the replacement to be `"<b><font color=\"red\">$1</font></b>"` should also work.